# How to filter a tibble using a variable as the argument of a function in R

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I think this problem is very common but I can't find the answer. I want to filter a `tibble` using a variable as an argument in a function. I tried several different ways without success.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(c = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"))

cc <- c("a", "b")


filtervar <- function(df, v) {
  filter(c == v)
  return(df2)
}

filtervar(df, "a")
#> Error in c == v: comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
filtervar(df, cc[1])
#> Error in c == v: comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
filtervar(df, {{cc[1]}})
#> Error in c == v: comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Comment: what is `df2` in the return.  Also, where is `df` passed into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `filter` takes the data as well.  Here, the data was not specified.  It may occur when we copy a part of function where we also use `%>%` i.e. `iris %>% filter(Species == "setosa")`.  In the Op's code, it may read as `filter(Species == "setosa")` and there is no way to know from which data that column comes from

```
filtervar <- function(df, v) {
  filter(df, c == v)
 
}
```

-testing

```
> filtervar(df, 'a')
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  c    
  <chr>
1 a    
2 a    
3 a    
> filtervar(df, cc[1])
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  c    
  <chr>
1 a    
2 a    
3 a
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake.